# issue with IF statement returning unexpected result

Tags: php, html

I am trying to achieve the following...

Each 'element' should have the option to choose **one** 'sibling' from a select dropdown, the siblings are chosen from all of the other elements, the sibling cannot be itself, but a sibling doesn't have to be assigned. If one is assigned it should be selected by default in the select list.

```
    <?php echo $sibling; ?>
    <select name="sibling">
        <option value="none">none</option> 
        <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                if($row['element']!=$element){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['element'].'" ';
                    if($row['sibling']==$sibling){
                        echo 'selected="selected"';
                    }
                    echo '>'.$row['element'].'</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

I have almost achieved what I want but for some reason the code doesn't add `selected="selected"` to the right option.

I'd appreciate any guidance anyone could give in where I may be going wrong? I'm fairly new to PHP so I may be going about this in the wrong way.

`$element` and `$sibling` are equal to `$row['element']` and `$row['sibling']` for the corresponding `$id` which is an index that is passed to the page on a query string.

**UPDATE: FOUND ANSWER**

So with a little investigation this was glaringly obvious.

The line containing...
`if($row['sibling']==$sibling)`

should have been...
`if($row['element']==$sibling){`

Thanks to @RyanS for suggesting the var dump.

Comment: We don't know what your variables contain dude. Try to find out why they don't equal, print them beforehand and see.

Comment: Before your if statement try var_dump($row['sibling'], $sibling); Check all the results, you should be able to find the issue there

Comment: @DanyCaissy I've updated the question with what the variables contain.

Comment: Can you post a little more of the surrounding code, particularly the parts where $element and $sibling are defined?